# AWS cognito sdk, AdminCreateUserCommand takes 1.579s to create the user, someone know how to improve the response time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

This is the code of the function, this is my pre-sign up lambda triggered when someone is sign-in with external provider like google. The big problem it's understand why cognito needs so much time to create a user!

```
const cognitoIdentityProviderClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});
const createUser = async ({
  userPoolId,
  email,

}) => {
  const adminCreateUserCommand = new AdminCreateUserCommand({
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    Username: email,
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: 'email',
        Value: email
      },
      {
        Name: 'email_verified',
        Value: 'TRUE'
      },
    ],
  });

  const { User } = await cognitoIdentityProviderClient.send(adminCreateUserCommand);
  return User;
};
```

I'm expecting to create a new user in max 500ms.